# Complexity of this algorithm in big O notation?

Tags: python, algorithm, big-o

```
def ways(n, coin):
    if n < 0 or len(coin) == 0:
        return 0
    if n > 0:
        return ways(n, coin[:-1]) + ways(n-coin[-1], coin)
    return 1
```

Called like so:

`ways(100, [1, 5, 10, 25, 50])` with an output of `292`

The algorithm calculates the number of ways that one can make change for 100 using only 50, 25, 10, 5, 1.  The original problem uses $1 and 50 cents, 25 cents, etc...but I've simplified this by multiplying by 100.

My problem is as follows.  What is the big-o complexity?

The algorithm seems to branch out by a factor of 2, but its not quite `O(2^N)` as can be seen by having a depth of greater than 292 with an input of N=5.

I note the number of ways it can branch out depends.  For instance, one possible way can be from n=100, to n=50, to n=0.  Two branches, another way is n=50, n=25, n=0, etc etc.  And I know that the maximum depth possible for one of the branches is N.

So it must be `O(2^M)` but what is M in relation to N?

NOTE: Sorry if this caused confusion, but n = the current value of money, and i'm assuming (capital) N is the length of the coin array

Comment: i thin you need to use generator functions : http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/LRGF.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ollie gave the right answer for the complexity in *n* with coins constant as shows this time graphic computed with your function and drawn with matplotlib (with some smoothing) :
[image: Time computing ways() with coins constant]

We recognize a nice Parabola  (n^2)

If we take n as a constant and make number of coins vary, (coins randomly generated), the curve is much steeper, and as you thought exponential

[image: Time computing ways() with n fixed]

There are better algorithms as [memoized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) version :

```python
# memways(n, k, coins) = number of ways of making 
# change of n with less or equal k coins
calculated = {}
def memways(n, k, coins):
    if n<0:
        return 0
    if (n, k) in calculated:
        return calculated[n,k]
    if k == 0:
        v = 1
    else:
        v = memways(n-coins[k], k, coins) + memways(n, k-1, coins)
    calculated[n,k] = v
    return v
```

Comment: Graphs! Nice answer :)

Answer (score 1):

`O(n^2)`.

It's a recursive function over `n`, modifying only `coins` in the recursive call, giving `n^2`.

The addition of the second recursive call is inconsequential, since it is over some `x < n`.